# The difference between "in many games" and "in as many games"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between **in many games** and **in as many games**?

I saw this in a [news article](https://talksport.com/football/595430/liverpool-jurgen-klopp-sadio-mane-mohamed-salah-burnley/):

> The Reds usurped champions Manchester City at the top of the Premier League table with a convincing 3-0 win at Turf Moor on Saturday evening.
>
> The Senegal international, who scored his fourth goal **in as many games**, became annoyed after apparently failing to receive a pass from Mohamed Salah late on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In many games" means in large number of games.

"In as many games" can't be understood without context because it means in the same number of games as previously mentioned.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/in-as-many-days-weeks-games-etc

Comment: The Senegal international, who scored his fourth goal in as many games, became annoyed after apparently failing to receive a pass from Mohamed Salah late on.... so the meaning is that he played 4 matches and scored 4 goals, do you mean that?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelsamed - Yes, that's exactly what that means. But please, going forward, only use a single question mark, spell _you_ as "you" (not "u"), and do not use emojis in comments.